# Retrieve EBIT from XBRL documents

Tags: sec, edgar

It appears that EBIT information is not very uniform across different XBRL documents.

Cross comparing data with other sources, such as Yahoo, I have seen some XBRL use the fact `us-gaap:OperatingIncomeLoss` to store it if using US-GAAP, or `ifrs-full:ProfitLossBeforeTax` if using IFRS.

However, sometimes it looks like they also use `us-gaap:IncomeLossFromContinuingOperationsBeforeIncomeTaxesMinorityInterestAndIncomeLossFromEquityMethodInvestments` or `us-gaap:IncomeLossFromContinuingOperationsBeforeIncomeTaxesExtraordinaryItemsNoncontrollingInterest`.

And sometimes many of those are actually filled with different values, so there is no way to know which one is correct.

Is there a more reliable way to retrieve EBIT data?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not about quant finance but accounting.

Comment: @LocalVolatility Could you suggest somewhere where I could post this question instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `getFundamentals(ticker)` provided by the package `eodhistoricaldata-api` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/eodhistoricaldata-api).

The library returns **EBIT** information, and other fundamentals (**quarterly/yearly** income statements, balance sheets, cash flow statements). The data is provided in **JSON** - no need to parse XBRL.

For example:

```
"Highlights": {
    "MarketCapitalization": 54915055616,
    "MarketCapitalizationMln": "54915.0556",
    "EBITDA": 616286976,
    "PERatio": null,
    "PEGRatio": "-1.5700",
    "WallStreetTargetPrice": "321.8900",
    "BookValue": "26.2790",
    "DividendShare": null,
    "DividendYield": null,
    "EarningsShare": "-4.8500",
    "EPSEstimateCurrentYear": "-6.5600",
    "EPSEstimateNextYear": "-2.0000",
    "EPSEstimateNextQuarter": "-1.6700",
    "MostRecentQuarter": "2018-09-30",
    "ProfitMargin": "-0.1022",
    "OperatingMarginTTM": "-0.0710",
    "ReturnOnAssetsTTM": "-0.0271",
    "ReturnOnEquityTTM": "-0.3397",
    "RevenueTTM": "17523644416.00",
    "RevenuePerShareTTM": "103.3240",
    "QuarterlyRevenueGrowthYOY": "1.2860",
    "GrossProfitTTM": "2222487000.00",
    "DilutedEpsTTM": "-10.5600",
    "QuarterlyEarningsGrowthYOY": null
},
// ...
"Income_Statement": {
        "currency_symbol": "USD",
        "quarterly": {
            "2018-09-30": {
                "date": "2018-09-30",
                "filing_date": "2018-11-02",
                "researchDevelopment": "350848000.00",
                "effectOfAccountingCharges": null,
                "incomeBeforeTax": "271320000.00",
                "minorityInterest": "1344731000.00",
                "netIncome": "311516000.00",
                "sellingGeneralAdministrative": "729876000.00",
                "grossProfit": "1523665000.00",
                "ebit": "442941000.00",
                "operatingIncome": "442941000.00",
                "otherOperatingExpenses": null,
                "interestExpense": "-169858000.00",
                "extraordinaryItems": null,
                "nonRecurring": null,
                "otherItems": null,
                "incomeTaxExpense": "16647000.00",
                "totalRevenue": "6824413000.00",
                "totalOperatingExpenses": "6381472000.00",
                "costOfRevenue": "5300748000.00",
                "totalOtherIncomeExpenseNet": "-171621000.00",
                "discontinuedOperations": null,
                "netIncomeFromContinuingOps": "254673000.00",
                "netIncomeApplicableToCommonShares": "311516000.00"
            },
            // ...
"Balance_Sheet": {
        "currency_symbol": "USD",
        "quarterly": {
            "2018-09-30": {
                "date": "2018-09-30",
                "filing_date": "2018-11-02",
                "intangibleAssets": "291476000.00",
                "totalLiab": "23409144000.00",
                "totalStockholderEquity": "4508838000.00",
                "deferredLongTermLiab": "0.00",
                "otherCurrentLiab": "2266778000.00",
                "totalAssets": "29262713000.00",
                "commonStock": "171000.00",
                "otherCurrentAssets": "158627000.00",
                "retainedEarnings": "-5457315000.00",
                "otherLiab": "2285172000.00",
                "goodWill": "65226000.00",
                "otherAssets": "1233979000.00",
                "cash": "2967504000.00",
                "totalCurrentLiabilities": "9775324000.00",
                "shortLongTermDebt": "2106538000.00",
                "otherStockholderEquity": "8271000.00",
                "propertyPlantEquipment": "19733969000.00",
                "totalCurrentAssets": "7920491000.00",
                "longTermInvestments": "17572000.00",
                "netTangibleAssets": "4152136000.00",
                "shortTermInvestments": "0.00",
                "netReceivables": "1155001000.00",
                "longTermDebt": "9726589000.00",
                "inventory": "3314127000.00",
                "accountsPayable": "3596984000.00",
                "totalPermanentEquity": "0.00",
                "noncontrollingInterestInConsolidatedEntity": "0.00",
                "temporaryEquityRedeemableNoncontrollingInterests": "0.00",
                "accumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncome": "0.00",
                "additionalPaidInCapital": "0.00",
                "commonStockTotalEquity": "0.00",
                "preferredStockTotalEquity": "0.00",
                "retainedEarningsTotalEquity": "0.00",
                "treasuryStock": "0.00"
            },
            // ...
"Cash_Flow": {
        "currency_symbol": "USD",
        "quarterly": {
            "2018-09-30": {
                "date": "2018-09-30",
                "filing_date": "2018-11-02",
                "investments": null,
                "changeToLiabilities": "895197000.00",
                "totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities": "-560965000.00",
                "netBorrowings": "-221931000.00",
                "totalCashFromFinancingActivities": "-84218000.00",
                "changeToOperatingActivities": "98770000.00",
                "netIncome": "311516000.00",
                "changeInCash": "739728000.00",
                "totalCashFromOperatingActivities": "1391281000.00",
                "depreciation": "502825000.00",
                "otherCashflowsFromInvestingActivities": "128600000.00",
                "dividendsPaid": "0.00",
                "changeToInventory": "-55055000.00",
                "changeToAccountReceivables": "-587594000.00",
                "salePurchaseOfStock": "0.00",
                "otherCashflowsFromFinancingActivities": "42839000.00",
                "changeToNetincome": "179168000.00",
                "capitalExpenditures": "-559765000.00"
            },
```

The package supports client-side (React, React Native, Angular, Vue, etc.), and server-side (Node.js, etc.) JavaScript.